# How do I join with count() in Laravel?

Tags: sql, laravel

I have two tables `shops` and `products`. I can get all shops but want to join so that I can know how many products aa shop has. I have tried this but it returns an empty table.

```
$shops = DB::table('shops')
            ->select('*','COUNT(shop_id) FROM products')
            ->join('shops.id','=','products.shop_id')
            ->get();
```

I have tried using SQL but return one shop and count of all products

```
SELECT * FROM `shops` JOIN (SELECT shop_id, COUNT(shop_id) FROM products AS KK) AS KKK on shops.id = KKK.shop_id
```

How do I change the query so that I get all shops and number of products each shop has?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you wrote proper Laravel Relations between this two tables, you can use [withCount()](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#counting-related-models) method:

```
Shop::withCount('products')->get();
```

But if you wanna use `join`:

```
\DB::table('shops')->join('products', 'products.shop_id', '=', 'shops.id')
->select('shops.*', DB::raw('count(products.id) as KK'))
->groupBy('shops.id')
->get()
```

Comment: I added relations and used eloquent with `withCount()` method. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

**Try this:-**

```
$shops = DB::table('shops')
        ->join('products', 'products.shop_id', '=', 'shops.id')
        ->select('shops.id as id', DB::raw("count(products.id) as count"))
        ->groupBy('shops.id')
        ->get();
```